# Wrap text in Flutter but take as little space as possible

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a container which contains text that should automatically wrap. This works by wrapping a `Expanded` around my text. However, I want the container to take up as little width as possible (as wide as the text). As soon as I add `Expanded` to my container, the container will take up all the space.

Without `Expanded`, the width is good as long as the text width is smaller than the available width:

```
 ---------------------------
| Some text that won't wrap |
 ---------------------------
```

With `Expanded`, the text will wrap, but the container is unnecessarily wide.

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------
| Some text that will wrap                                     |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Consider using a `Flexible` widget instead.

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Flexible` widget takes only the needed space while the `Expanded` takes all available space.

So in your case. You should use a `Flexible` widget instead of the `Expanded` widget you have used.